# SVG connect two points with a line, and automatically update the line if a point is moved

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I'd like to connect two points (circles) with a line:

```js
window.onclick = () => {
    document.getElementById('c2').setAttribute("cx", 150);
}
```

```html
<svg>
  <circle cx="10" cy="10" r="2" id="c1" />
  <circle cx="90" cy="50" r="2" id="c2" />
  <line x1="10" y1="10" x2="90" y2="50" stroke="black" />
</svg><br>
Click here to move a circle.
```

such that if I modify the center of any `<circle>` with `setAttribute("cx", 150)` then the line **automatically follows the new circle position**.

Is there a way to do this with `<use>`? Something like (pseudo-code):

```
<svg>
  <circle cx="10" cy="10" r="2" id="c1" />
  <circle cx="90" cy="50" r="2" id="c2" />
  <use x1=xlink:c1:cx y1=xlink:c1:cy x2=xlink:c2:cx y2=xlink:c2:cy stroke="black" type="line" />
</svg>
```

Goal: I don't want to have to set the coordinates two times, in both the `circle` and `line`. Instead I would like to set the coordinates once, and that the `line` uses a reference to the `circle` elements.

Note: I have read [SVG connect two points with a line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17272907/svg-connect-two-points-with-a-line) but it did not help.

Comment: How to do this @RobertLongson?

Comment: on click you can set both the cx of the circle and the x2 of the line to the same value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [`<marker>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/marker) that can be placed on start, middle and end of an element.

```js
window.onclick = () => {
    document.getElementById('l1').setAttribute("x2", 150);
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 200 100" width="200">
  <defs>
    <marker id="circle" viewBox="0 0 4 4" refX="2"
      refY="2" markerWidth="4" markerHeight="4">
      <circle cx="2" cy="2" r="2" />
    </marker>
  </defs>
  <line id="l1" x1="10" y1="10" x2="90" y2="50" stroke="black"
    marker-start="url(#circle)" marker-end="url(#circle)"/>
</svg><br>
Click here to move a circle.
```